# The Command-T how to use current file own NERDTree bookmark as search directory?

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I like NERDTree and Command-T.
So i want use Command-T search file for current project. (I use NERDTree bookmark as project).
Because the Command-T use `:CommandT <path>` to active search , and default `<path>` is pwd. I want change the `<path>` to current file own NERDTree bookmark path.

*Like this:*

I have a bookmark called `TestProject` and the path is `~/testproject`.

Now ,I'm writing file is `~/testproject/class/test.php`, If use `:CommandT`, I will get search directory is `~/testproject/class/` . But i want search global project (`~/test/project`),and i don't want to type `:CommandT ~/testproject/`.

Comment: You should make up your mind and choose one method.

Comment: I using python script create a vim plugin implemented my mind. Thx! :-)!

Comment: https://github.com/liukebin/code/blob/master/vim/vimrc

Answer (score 0):

Completely disregarding NERDTree, you can configure your CommandT mapping to include your project root by default. To make it flexible, you can load the project root for each vim session dynamically from an environment variable:

```
"If the $H environment variable is available, assume it contains CommandT's root dir
if !empty($H)
  nnoremap <silent> <Leader>t :CommandT $H<CR>
else
  nnoremap <silent> <Leader>t :CommandT<CR>
endif
```

Or more simply, you could use $PWD, which should reflect the directory you started your `vim` session in.

Regarding the solution you propose, you can indeed `cd` in NERDTree by position the cursor on the node you want to cd to and then pressing `cd` (see `:h NERDTree-cd`). That changes the output of `:pwd`/`:!pwd` for the `NERDTree` buffer and if you start `CommandT` while in the `NERDTree` buffer, `CommandT` will use the new value for searching. 
The problem is, `CommandT` will attempt to open your selected file in your most recently accessed editing buffer, which won't be affected by the `cd`ing in the `NERDTree` buffer. And now since version 1.3.1 of `CommandT` attempts to open the selection using a relative path (relative from the `:pwd` from the `NERDTree buffer`), it most likely won't work.

Below is a `git-format`ted  patch for CommandT v1.3.1 to make it work:

```
From cf4569af2f5d06673d96ac0f798c22612b5579f5 Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
From: Petr Skocik <pskocik@gmail.com>
Date: Fri, 1 Aug 2014 02:10:35 +0200
Subject: [PATCH] open selection by its absolute rather than relative path

---
 ruby/command-t/controller.rb | 1 +
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)

diff --git a/ruby/command-t/controller.rb b/ruby/command-t/controller.rb
index 6026aca..4774345 100644
--- a/ruby/command-t/controller.rb
+++ b/ruby/command-t/controller.rb
@@ -240,6 +240,7 @@ module CommandT
       selection = File.expand_path selection, @path
       selection = relative_path_under_working_directory selection
       selection = sanitize_path_string selection
+      selection = VIM::pwd + '/' + selection
       ensure_appropriate_window_selection
       ::VIM::command "silent #{command} #{selection}"
     end
-- 
1.9.1
```

Answer (score 0):

The "next" branch of Command-T (not yet in a released version) and specifically this commit:

https://github.com/wincent/Command-T/commit/ebcda3ce2e90211345eab89fd972e22b75883440

add the option of anchoring the search to the nearest SCM directory from the currently-edited file, or from Vim's PWD (configurable). This might address this use case.